# how big are the FETs used to drive Tesla cars

Tags: motor

So I've been looking into bldc  and motor drivers lately (ESCs). Generally larger the BLDC motor the larger the FETs need to be in order to suppluly needed current. One can do this either by using a higher powered FET or stacking them up (quite literally). Tesla cars use motors that are quite large. How large do the FETs need to be to run them?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A little googling suggests these are the parts [IXGX72N60](http://ixapps.ixys.com/DataSheet/DS100011A(IXGX72N60C3H1%29.pdf)

Comment: Good find.. +1.

Comment: I hope they are not using PunchThrough IGBT's....

Comment: @JonRB here's part of my source for that http://www.teslamotorsclub.com/showthread.php/20709-34-Salvage-auction/page13

Comment: Oh i'm not refuting it, just surprised. There are a number of advantages with NPT over PT. I guess the switching and conduction losses are attractive... but I would still take a 4th gen NPT over a 2nd gen PT

Comment: 29 left on Digikey, not enough to build my own Roadster. Aborting. Thx for the answer though. I'll be fure to dig through the forums when I have more time.

Answer (score 16):

They don't use MOSFETs at all- they'd be too expensive in such high voltage (375V battery voltage). They use IGBTs, in banks amounting to something like [66-72 total](http://auto.howstuffworks.com/tesla-roadster.htm) of them for all three phases, reportedly.

The Tesla motor can (briefly) produce something like 400HP (300kW)- some of the data says 185kW which may be more sustainable- which implies currents in the 250-800A region. So maybe 60A/600V IGBTs, but I'm not sure anyone has publicly given the part number.

Nice car by the way, a colleague has one.

Comment: Good guess, the datasheet for IXGX72N60 from the other answer says 72A/600V.